# Can't uninstall Microsoft Express Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, visual-studio-2013

I'm using windows 7 professional edition, 32 bits, and installed Microsoft Express Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop, with Update 3.

I tried to uninstall it from Control Panel, a "repair/uninstall" dialog box comes out, then, it just keep restarting. Every time windows restarted, the dialog box will come again.

Is there an easy way to uninstall MS Express Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop?

update after the comment to upload system log.

In "AppData\Local", I only find

C:\Users\athos\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\vspdmc.lock

this has only one line, does not look like a log.

C:\Users\athos\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\SQM

this is a binary file. I don't understand the content.

C:\Users\athos\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0

There are some files, but none looks like a log.

Comment: look inside the temp folder (under your user profile->appdata-local) for log files and upload them.

Comment: @magicandre1981 pls see the question updated -- I didn't find any log file :(

Comment: I told you to look **INSIDE** the **TEMP** folder